# Call scenario inside a step - Cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin

Hello everyone,
I have a scenario with this given step

```
Scenario: Registration

Given I am logged in
.
.
```

And I want to use an existing scenario which is "login with valid username and password" in this step.

Do you have any idea how to call it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should not call another scenario from within a step, this is not a good practice. Instead, you can use a @Before hook that performs the login or a Background step that performs the login. You can also use a custom tag (e.g. @loginRequired) in a @Before hook where it checks if the current scenario being executed has that tag and perform the login if that is the case, like the example below:

```
@loginRequired
Scenario: Registration
Given ...
When ...
Then ...

@Before
public void setUp(Scenario scenario) {
    if(scenario.getSourceTagNames().contains("@loginRequired")) {
        // Perform Login
    }
}
```